# Question about increment a key value in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, increment

I'm new to python and have a question about incrementing key values in dictionary! I was able to google around and found the solutions - **like get() or defaultdict()**. however, I still don't understand the logic behind it. Would really appreciate your help if you can explain to me, thanks!!

So my original code is this:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
my_dict = {}
for item in list:
    my_dict[item] += 1
print(my_dict)
```

This code throws a keyerror, I understand it's because of the non-existent key value.
Here's a solution I attempted:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

mydict = {}
for item in list:
    if item not in mydict.keys():
        mydict[item] = 1
    else:
        mydict[item] += 1
print(mydict)
```

However, the output doesn't really increment the values and gives me this:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1}
```

I thought when it loops through each item in the list, it should check the "if" statement every time, so I'm confused why it's not happening here.

Do you know if it's possible to make this work without using any of the function/method I mentioned above? Thank you so much!

Best,
Yuen

Comment: You are processing the five keys exactly one time each.  The `mydict[item] = 1` branch of the code gets executed every time, `mydict[item] += 1` never gets used at all.  What were you expecting to happen differently?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! It makes complete sense! So I'm hoping the results to be: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through your list so the values you are checking are `'a'` then `'b'` and so on. Each one of those doesn't exist in the dict yet so it enters the `if` clause and does: `mydict[item] = 1`.
If you want to see the values getting updated you need to go over the same key more than once.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply it makes sense! What do you mean by go over the same key more than once, can you provide an example?

Comment: A simple example:
```mydict = {}

mydict['a'] = 1

mydict['a'] += 1

# now mydict['a'] is 2
```

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your list you have items that are unique, if you have elements repeted, you would see what you are trying to do, i.e.:

```
>>> import random
>>> a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for item in [random.choice(a_list) for i in range(30)]:
...     try:
...             my_dict[item] += 1
...     except KeyError:
...             my_dict[item] = 1
...
>>> my_dict
{'a': 8, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'c': 12, 'b': 1}
```

What is not entirely clear is, if you want to update the "Key value" itself or the associated value of that particular key-value pair.

Comment: Thank you so much it makes sense! I do wish to update the key value itself and get the result like: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}